# Retain visibility of Div when input has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, focus

I have an `a`, which when hovered, displays a `div` within it.  Inside that `div` is an `input(type="text")`.  When the user hovers over the `a`, the div remains visible.  However, the problem is that when they type in the `input` field, if the mouse is not over the `a` or the `div`, the `div` becomes hidden and the `input` stops receiving input.

How can I set it up so that as long as the `input` has focus, the `div` will remain visible?

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7TS62/) that explains it a little better.

Comment: post code here also please

Comment: you can use the focus state on input, in css it's litlle possibilities http://jsfiddle.net/7TS62/1/

Comment: @GCyrillus, That seems to work, but what about adapting it to a more complex structure?  http://jsfiddle.net/7TS62/2/

Comment: the answer of Jack Zelig is your hint, use add/remove classname instead :) CSS is limited and not adapted for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
<a>
    <div class="hidden">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</a>

$("input")
.on("focus", function(){
    $("div").removeClass("hidden");
})
.on("blur", function(){
    $("div").addClass("hidden");
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/kj87J/)

**EDIT**:

The `input:focus` solution is much cleaner, apart from the fact that it doesn't work in IE7 or below (which is hopefully irrelevant for you).

Comment: your solution is fine, but you should use add/remove classname, cause after blur, display:none might override the :hover css rule and never show again untill refresh of the page

Comment: This solution works great with my more complex structure.  Thanks!